# What is Extend-protocol in a Jepsen context?

Tags: syntax, clojure, jepsen

I'm new to clojure and I am trying to figure out what Jepsen does, a software used to check consistency of distributed system.

- My questions are:

  1. What does extend-protocol do?
  2. To be more specific, In [Jepsen.Generator](https://github.com/jepsen-io/jepsen/blob/master/jepsen/src/jepsen/generator.clj), what is `op` in the `Protocol`.
  3. What does [mix](https://github.com/jepsen-io/jepsen/blob/master/jepsen/src/jepsen/generator.clj#L253) mean in the context

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does extend-protocol do?

A protocol is an abstract thing that looks like an interface in Java. It does nothing, but some other entities may implement it. In Java, you declare a class that implements an interface. In Clojure, you extend a 
particular protocol with a custom type declared either with `deftype` or `defrecord` calling `extend-protocol` on it.

When extending a protocol with a type, you need to specify implementation for signatures mentioned in that protocol.

A good example might be JSON serialization. Say, the protocol would look like as follows:

```
(defprotocol JSON
  (to-json [obj]))
```

If you call `(to-json ...)` on any value, you'll have an error saying that there is no `to-json` implementation for that type. You need to extend it:

```
(extend-protocol JSON

  Integer
  (to-json [obj] (str obj))

  Boolean
  (to-json [obj]
    (if obj "true" "false")))
```

Now that, calling `(to-json 42)` and `(to-json false)` will work. You may extend that protocol for the rest of types: floats, array, maps and so on.

> what is op in the Protocol

Protocols do not have implementations, only signatures. `os` is a signature of some function that just takes three arguments: `[gen test process]`. It's up to what should it return. As an example, you may refer the [line #46](https://github.com/jepsen-io/jepsen/blob/master/jepsen/src/jepsen/generator.clj#L46) where its behavior is implemented for the `clojure.lang.AFunction` type. Since I'm not familiar with jepsen, I cannot say more on that.

> What does mix mean in the context

I think its docstring is pretty clear as well as the code is. I takes a collection of gens. If it's empty, the result would be a special Generator instance named `void`. It's an anonymous type that extends Generator protocol returning just `nil` when calling `op` without any computations.

It the `gens` are not empty, the code returns an instance of Generator type with such `op` implementation that takes a random `gen` when executing `op`.

Hope that will help.